# How to code with Jquery to extract or escape some specific html tags from a text editor

Tags: jquery, html, tinymce

I am trying to remove some specific html tags from a string which comes from a text editor #Textarea.
I have a textarea where in button click event. i get all the content of the text editor and want to assign the content to another html tag. but before assigning i want remove some of the HTML elements or in other word want to allow only  HTML tags ( p,lists,table).
I am using tinyMCE text editor and my function on button click event is

```
 function AssignContents() {
  // takes the specific tag ID 
 var ref=$('.data_button').attr('data_id');
    var textEditorContent = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
    $('#'+ref).html(textEditorContent);
}
```

But when i save data in database table it looks strange.
for example. If i write in text editor "hello wold" and using the button click event the bellow given function assigns content of tinyMCE to textarea and after form submit and saving it to database table. the value in database table looks like bellow.

```
&lt;p&gt;Hello World!&lt;/p&gt;
```

But i want only `<p>hello world </p>` to be stored in database not other stuffs.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace for make this:

```
$('#'+ref).html(textEditorContent.replace(/&lt/g,'<').replace(/&gt/g, '>'));
```

Or if you want keep tag you can use `unescape()` function.

```js
$(".d").html(unescape($(".d").html()))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d">&lt;p&gt;Hello World!&lt;/p&gt;</div>
```